# How can an instance of an UITableViewCell, which was created by an instance of my ViewControllers, tell the ViewController, to do something?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I created a instance of my ViewController(TimeLineViewController), which will be presented. This ViewController contains a UITableView, which gets the cells from a instance of my TableViewCell. So the ViewController creates an instance of the TableCellView.
The TableViewCell contains a UITextView with enabled weblinks. Now I want to disable the function that safari opens. I did a subclass of the UITextView and:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{   NSLog(@"request: %@", request); //Console shows the link
}
```

Now I want that with a click on the weblink a new ViewController(WebViewController) appears. The problem is that the TableViewCell can´t "open" a new ViewController. So I tried this:
In the TableViewCell:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{   NSLog(@"request: %@", request);
    TimeLineViewController * web = [[TimeLineViewController alloc]init];
    [web loadView];
}
```

And in the ViewController:

```
- (void)loadWeb{
    WebViewController *lust = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    lust.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:lust animated:YES];
    [lust release];
}
```

The problem is that he always just reload the TimeLineViewController, but doesn't load the WebViewController. Why? How can I fix it?
(I know that the WebViewController doesn't get the weblink in my posted code and I know how to do it. That shouldn't be the problem, when I know, how to fix my problem.)

Thanks for your help! If you have questions, just ask - Sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE**:
I did what Frank mention, but I doesn't work. I created a WebViewTableCellDelegate.h with:

```
@protocol WebViewTableCellDelegate
-(void)loadWeb;
@end
```

Then I created a instance variable of the WebViewDelegate in the TableViewCell:

```
__weak NSObject <WebViewTableCellDelegate> *_delegate;
```

and in the .m:

```
@interface UITextView (Override)
@end

@class WebView, WebFrame;
@protocol WebPolicyDecisionListener;

@implementation UITextView (Override)

- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{   NSLog(@"request: %@", request);
    [_delegate loadWeb];
}

@end
```

In my TimeLineViewController I implemented the WebViewTableCellDelegate with <> and in the line, where I create the cells, I set the owner to self:

```
  TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableCell;
    }
```

Why doens´t it work? There is no error-warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Create a `WebViewTableCellDelegate` protocol (look up how to create a protocol on Apple's site). The protocol should include your `loadWeb:` method.
2. Have your TimeLineViewController implement the protocol and give your `UITextView` subclass an instance variable of type `<WebViewTableCellDelegate>`.
3. When you're creating the table view cell, set it's delegate to `self` (the TimeLineViewController).
4. When someone taps a link, call `[delegate loadWeb:request]`
5. Have your `loadWeb:` method accept an `NSURLRequest` and load it into the web view.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to put a `UIWebView` in every cell.  Consider an implementation where you simply utilize the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method in the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to present your `UIWebView` when a particular cell is tapped.

Comment: I dont want to do that, because when someone press on a row a uiactionsheet opens. I just want a WebView, when the link is pressed.

Comment: Consider using an accessory or a UIButton in your cell for the UIActionSheet?